# How many days should I measure a variable to get a good estimate of 'average' behavior?

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, convergence, measurement-error, measurement

I have data for individuals, spread over a number of days. My dataset is very large: it covers way more days than what is typically feasible to collect. I want to use this to create a 'benchmark' of sorts: a guideline on how many measurements (days) you need to have an average that can be expected to approach the 'real' average. The latter will be approximated by the average over all the days that are in my dataset, for every specific individual.

For example, I'm looking at a variable X, representing the distance someone traveled that day. How many days should I log X to get a good estimate of 'typical' distance traveled?

- I have **data for about a year**: 365 measurements per individual
- I calculate **grand averages per individual**: the best measure I can get for 'typical' behavior.
- I now create a vector of **expanding averages**: the first value is simply the value for the first day, the second value is the average
  of the first two days, the third value is the average of the first
  three days, etc.
- If I plot this vector, it will converge to the 'grand average'.  It is **typically impossible to log this data for that long**. Usually,
  only a couple of weeks can be logged. How much data is enough?

My current idea is to determine from which point (i.e., from how many log days onward) the expanding average never leaves a band around the grand average. For example, I could say that as soon as the expanding average never goes outside of the `grand average +/- (Y x the standard deviation)`. As soon as it doesn't, I could have stopped gathering data. If I take the average over all participants of when this 'good enough' day is, I can formulate a guideline: log at least X days to expect to be within a certain range of the true average.

Another approach I saw, was using **correlations**. For each day, the expanding average was correlated with the grand average. As soon as the correlation was high enough (and stayed high enough), there had been sufficient log days. Only reason why I'm not that big a fan here, is that it combines everything into a single value. Using the approach above, I can average over participants, see the SD of the required number of log days, the range, etc.

I feel like the methodology to deal with such matters has probably been described somewhere. Haven't found anything yet, though. Feels like I'm making things up as I go (and I kind of am). Is my approach reasonable?